# pyMel bug? Could not create desired MFn

Tags: python, warnings, maya, pymel

So when I call the nonLinear function with pymel and save it in a variable like this:

```
flare = pm.nonLinear(objName, type="flare")
```

and I want to get the name of the flare1 Input like this:

```
print flare[0]
```

I get this warning:

```
Warning: pymel.core.general : Could not create desired MFn. Defaulting to MFnDependencyNode.
```

Everything works fine and it doesn't break anything.

I have also searched for it but I didn't really get what the actual problem is or how to get rid of it.

Thanks to everyone looking into it.

Comment: Im on maya 2018 and running your code isn't outpting any error. Have you tried on a fresh scene with a simple cube to see if you have the same error ?

Comment: Hey, yeah it's still coming up.

Comment: It might be your version of PyMel, or your maya version. Try on another computer maybe. On which version of maya are you ? I might be able to try on another maya version than 2018.3

Comment: Okay, so I'm working on a MacBook with Maya 2018. I have tried it with a default cube as only object in the scene on mac and a windows machine, still occurs. The windows machine got the same Maya version.  Am I crazy :O

Comment: If you can try to install service packs and if doesn't work, asi for autodesk support. Im also on maya 2018, linux and it works. It might be just an issue in mac os

Comment: Yeah I will definitely go for the updates :D sounds like the only difference